# htaccess redirect rule for non existing directory

Tags: .htaccess

I want to create htaccess rule that make redirection if the directory does not exist.
For example: I want to redirect https://mywebsite.com/calendar to https://somewebsite.com
Note that directory /calendar does not exist on my root at all.

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Redirect ^calendar https://somewebsite/ [R=301, L]
```

but it does not work. When I type https://mywebsite.com/calendar I get 404 page.

Comment: What folder is your htaccess file located in? Are there any other rules in the htaccess?

Comment: And did yo enable the interpretation of such distributed configuration files (".htaccess")?

Comment: What entries do you see in your http sever's error log file?